# OnClickListener for the Recycler View returns nothing

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to build a simple voice recorder app. I've already posted on the website concerning the access of external storage. This problem is now solved but I've an another one concerning my RecyclerView.

I've followed a tutorial online in order to detect which view is clicked and play the audio accordingly (I use my RecyclerView to display all the recording files just created). Here's the tutorial in question : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXoGG2XTjzU

The problem is, the 'OnNoteClick' does absolutely nothing. How can I fix this ?

I created an interface with a function 'OnNoteClick' attached to it. I implemented this function in mainactivity.java. Basically, I've followed the tutorial.

```
\\\ Adapter Code
private OnNoteListener mOnNoteListener;

...

public RecyclerViewAdapter(@NonNull ArrayList<String> text, Context context, OnNoteListener onNoteListener) {
        Text = text;
        this.context = context;
        this.mOnNoteListener = onNoteListener;
    }
...
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view, mOnNoteListener);
        return holder;
    }
...
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView textView;
        CardView ParentLayout;
        OnNoteListener onNoteListener;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnNoteListener onNoteListener) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardtext);
            ParentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
            this.onNoteListener = onNoteListener;
            ParentLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onNoteListener.onNoteClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
    public interface OnNoteListener{
        void onNoteClick(int position);
    }

}
...
```

```
\\\ MainActivityCode
public class FileAndDirectoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewAdapter.OnNoteListener {
...
private void initRecyclerView() {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mNames, this, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
...
    @Override
    public void onNoteClick(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Good News : I'm working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
...
```

I expect the app to show a message reading "I'm working" or something like that but in reality, when i touch the cardview, nothing happens.

Comment: where is the bindViewHolder() method ?

Comment: Have you override method `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: I've not included the onBindViewHolder, but I do have it.

Comment: public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int i) {
        holder.textView.setText(Text.get(i));
        holder.ParentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Click on this card !");
            }
        });
    }

Comment: Yes, I have override the 'OnBindViewHolder'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int i) {
    holder.textView.setText(Text.get(i));
    holder.ParentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Click on this card !");
        }
    });
}
```

You set a new click listener on `ParentLayout` so it overwrites click listener that you set in constructor. Try it without and it should work:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int i) {
    holder.textView.setText(Text.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Adapter to below code and also Make sure you are fetching correct `id` of **cardView**

```
private OnNoteListener mOnNoteListener;

...

public RecyclerViewAdapter(@NonNull ArrayList<String> text, Context context, OnNoteListener onNoteListener) {
        Text = text;
        this.context = context;
        this.mOnNoteListener = onNoteListener;
    }
...
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cardview, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }
...
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView textView;
        CardView ParentLayout;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardtext);
            ParentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
            ParentLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mOnNoteListener.onNoteClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
    public interface OnNoteListener{
        void onNoteClick(int position);
    }

}
```

No need to pass listener on ViewHolder constructor, because you have `mOnNoteListener` as global varible.

Answer (score 0):

Here i given you clear explanation,

Create one common `Interface`, named as *CustomItemClickListenere*

```
public interface CustomItemClickListenere {
    public void onItemClick(View v, int position); }
```

Change your adapter class like below,

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<AddSingleItemList> data;

    private Context mContext;
    private CustomItemClickListenere listener;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<AddSingleItemList> data, CustomItemClickListenere listener) {
        this.data = data;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items_list_single_item, parent, false);
        final ViewHolder mViewHolder = new ViewHolder(mView);
        mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onItemClick(v, mViewHolder.getPosition());
            }
        });
        return mViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.itemTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(data.get(position).getTitle()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView itemTitle;
        public CardView cardView;

        ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            itemTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
            cardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        }
    }
}
```

adapter's xml *item_list_single_item* :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/person_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Here i have created on `Pojo` class for setting static items on `Recyclerview`, named as *AddSingleItemList* :

```
public class AddSingleItemList {
    private String title;
    long id;

    /**
     *
     * @param id
     * @param title
     */
    public AddSingleItemList(long id, String title) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Update you *RecyclerViewActivity* like below :

```
public class RecyclerViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView itemsList;
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<AddSingleItemList> data = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        itemsList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.items_list);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        itemsList.setLayoutManager(llm);
        itemsList.setHasFixedSize(true);

        //Add you items into the Recyclerview list
        data.add(new AddSingleItemList(1, "First Item"));
        data.add(new AddSingleItemList(2, "Second Item"));

        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, data, new CustomItemClickListenere() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
                Log.d("RecyclerViewActivity", "clicked position:" + position);
                Toast.makeText(RecyclerViewActivity.this, "Good News : I'm working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // do what ever you want to do with it
            }
        });
        itemsList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Finally you will get result as you raised in your question,

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I'm confused. I do not have a variable called "items" nor a variable called "listener"...

Comment: Android studio marks "ContentItem" (from public void bind), items.get(position) and listener as errors...

Comment: @Ricochet, check edited answer and let me know if any queries.

Comment: It does nothing. It's ok. I might be doing something wrong. I'll read more in details how does recyclerView works in order to fix the issue by myself. Thank you a lot for your help and sorry for the (probably) stupid question.

Comment: @Ricochet, Finally i edited every classes, please check and update whether you're getting result or not.

Comment: Grateful to help you

Comment: @Ricochet, please make sure to accept an answer for further references for future SO users

Answer (score 0):

Just create `setonclicklistener` of view in `onBind` method. And call `interface` method on that.

Like

```
mOnNoteListener.onNoteClick(pos);
```

`pos` integer as position got in `onBind` method

Comment: What is `onBind`?